# Converting Obj-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, layer

I'm having trouble converting this line to Swift:

```
(void)authenticateLayerWithUserID:(NSString *)userID completion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError * error))completion { }
```

Here's my line in Swift:

```
func authenticateLayerWithUserID(userID: NSString) {(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in }
```

*Anyone have some insight into what I'm not doing correctly?*

Comment: Are you trying to convert the method definition (in which case a hyphen is missing in the ObjC part) or a method call? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I'm not sure actually. It starts with - (void)authenticateLayerWithUserID:(NSString *)userID completion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError * error))completion { (with if/else code in here )}. I figured it was a function, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would translate this kind of function in Swift with a "completion handler":

```
func authenticateLayerWithUserID(userID: NSString, completion: (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    if userID == "Jack" {
        completion(success: true, error: nil)
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
authenticateLayerWithUserID("Jack", { (success, error) in
    println(success) // true
})
```

**EDIT:**

Following your comments, here's a new example within a class function, and with an "if else":

```
class MyClass {
    class func authenticateLayerWithUserID(userID: NSString, completion: (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
        if userID == "Jack" {
            completion(success: true, error: nil)
        } else {
            completion(success: false, error: nil)
        }
    }
}

MyClass.authenticateLayerWithUserID("Jack", completion: { (success, error) in
    println(success) // true
})

MyClass.authenticateLayerWithUserID("John", completion: { (success, error) in
    println(success) // false
})
```

Comment: This works great @eric-d , but when I try an if statement using the completion, I receive an error...  if completion(success: true, error: nil) { statement here ). Error says that type (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void () does not conform to protocol Boolean Type.

Comment: Don't do `if completion...`, the completion is here to wrap *the results*.

Comment: I see.. so then I would write completion: success, error: nil INSIDE of a valid if statement?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example. *It's just an example*, you can use `completion` anywhere in the function to "wrap" the results that will be passed to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a call to that method, it will look like this in Objective-C (I think you're using [this](https://github.com/layerhq/documentation/blob/master/quick-start/ios/authenticate.md):

```objective-c
[self authenticateLayerWithUserID:userIDString completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"Failed Authenticating Layer Client with error:%@", error);
            }
 }];
```

In Swift

```swift
var c: MyClass = MyClass()
    c.authenticateLayerWithUserID("user", completion: { (boolean, error) -> Void in


})
```